# My code is not working for negative value of parameter

Tags: php

I am new, If I did any mistake you can tell me or update my question.

I have a assignment, I tried hard to solve but its working only for positive value of parameter but not working for negative value. Here is my code. please help make complete. Desire output is commented.

```
<?php
    function custom_substr($str, $start,$end=999){
      $str_length = strlen($str);
      for($i=$start;$end>0&&$str_length>$i;$i++,$end--){
        echo $str[$i];
      }
    }
    echo custom_substr('abcdef', 1);     // bcdef
    echo "\n";
    echo custom_substr('abcdef', 1, 3);  // bcd
    echo "\n";
    echo custom_substr('abcdef', 0, 4);  // abcd
    echo "\n";
    echo custom_substr('abcdef', 0, 8);  // abcdef
    echo "\n";
    echo custom_substr('abcdef', -1, 1); // f
    echo "\n";
    echo custom_substr("abcdef", -1);    // returns "f"
    echo "\n";
    echo custom_substr("abcdef", -2);    // returns "ef"
    echo "\n";
    echo custom_substr("abcdef", -3, 1); // returns "d"
    echo "\n";
    echo custom_substr("abcdef", 0, -1);  // returns "abcde"
    echo "\n";
    echo custom_substr("abcdef", 2, -1);  // returns "cde"
    echo "\n";
    echo custom_substr("abcdef", 4, -4);  // returns false
    echo "\n";
    echo custom_substr("abcdef", -3, -1); // returns "de"

?>
```

My output is

```
bcdef
bcd
abcd
abcdef

abcdef
abcdef
```

And Desire output is

```
bcdef
bcd
abcd
abcdef
f
f
ef
d
abcde
cde

de
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not just use substring? instead of making your own function?

Comment: How about: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Did you turn off the `error_reporting`?

Comment: It's my College assignment, I need to make it without `substr` function @Naruto & @Timothy

Comment: Ow it's homework, I'm out..

Comment: I just need a guidance, please help me.

Comment: I also checked this question asked in many interview but not got answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with below code

```
function custom_substr($string, $start, $length = 999)
    {
      if($start > strlen($string)) { return false; }
      if(empty($length))           { return ''; }
      if($start < 0) { $start = max(0, $start + strlen($string)); }
      $end = ($length < 0) ? 
        strlen($string) + $length : 
        min(strlen($string), $start + $length);
      if($end < $start) { return false; }
      $length = $end - $start;
      $substr = substr($string, $start, $length);
      $string = substr($string, 0, $start).substr($string, $end);  
      return $substr;
    }

echo custom_substr('abcdef', 1);     // bcdef
echo "</br>";
echo custom_substr('abcdef', 1, 3);  // bcd
echo "</br>";
echo custom_substr('abcdef', 0, 4);  // abcd
echo "</br>";
echo custom_substr('abcdef', 0, 8);  // abcdef
echo "</br>";
echo custom_substr('abcdef', -1, 1); // f
echo "</br>";
echo custom_substr("abcdef", -1);    // returns "f"
echo "</br>";
echo custom_substr("abcdef", -2);    // returns "ef"
echo "</br>";
echo custom_substr("abcdef", -3, 1); // returns "d"
echo "</br>";
echo custom_substr("abcdef", 0, -1);  // returns "abcde"
echo "</br>";
echo custom_substr("abcdef", 2, -1);  // returns "cde"
echo "</br>";
echo custom_substr("abcdef", 4, -4);  // returns false
echo "</br>";
echo custom_substr("abcdef", -3, -1); // returns "de"
?>
```

as you can find this from here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

You could do by this way also.

```
    function custom_substr($str, $start,$end=999){
      $str_length = strlen($str);
      if($start<0){//Change your start position if negative
        $start = $str_length + $start;
      }
      if($end<0){//Change your end position if negative
        $end = $str_length + $end-$start;
      }
      for($i=$start;$end>0&&$str_length>$i;$i++,$end--){
        echo $str[$i];
      }
    }
```

Check this demo : https://eval.in/659236